# Python iterable collection that wraps a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, iteration, iterable

I'm trying to modify the following code, so that MyCollection will wrap a dictionary. I still have to implement the **iter** and **next** methods in order to have the "for element in collection" functionality. I know that can be easily done by iterating through the values, but I am required to do it like this. Can someone help me ?

```
class MyCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []  // should be {}

    def __iter__(self):
            '''
        Return an iterator
        '''
        self._iterPoz = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        '''
        Returns the next element of the iteration
        '''
        if self._iterPoz >= len(self._data):
            raise StopIteration()
        rez = self._data[self._iterPoz]
        self._iterPoz = self._iterPoz + 1
        return rez
```

Comment: If you want the user to iterate over the inner data, just `return iter(self._data)` for `__iter__` and then you don't need to provide `__next__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - good point but it looks like he wants to iterate values, not keys, so `return iter(self._data.values())`.

Comment: Its difficult to do this by indexing because dicts are indexed by their names. You'd need to grab a list of names up front but then you risk the dict changing during iteration and raising `KeyError`. I don't think we can answer this question without more details about why you have such a strange restriction and what exactly that restriction is.

Comment: @tdelaney It's part of a project for my programming class. My professor asked me to have an iterable data structure and showed me this example that uses lists. The thing is, this collection will be used in a bigger project that is currently using dictionaries so it should work like one, except that i will be able to iterate through it.

Comment: @SebastianGrigor - you can iterate a dict's keys, values, or key/value pairs depending on which subfunction you call. The big question is what you want to iterate. If its just the values of `self._dict` then `iter(self._data.values())` is what you want. You could potentially  return `tuple(self._data.values())` to take a snapshot of the values.

Comment: @tdelaney The answer i was looking for was `iter(self._data.values())`. I just tried it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This begins with a design decision. When you iterate `MyCollection` what data do you want? If its the values of the contained dictionary you can return its iterator and then you don't implement `__next__` at all.

```
class MyCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def __iter__(self):
            '''
        Return an iterator of contained values
        '''
        return iter(self._data.values())
```